# Why can't Processing 2.0b8 find a class or type named "Set"?

Tags: processing

I'm trying to walk through a [Processing tutorial](http://blog.blprnt.com/blog/blprnt/your-random-numbers-getting-started-with-processing-and-data-visualization) and hitting a wall. I can't even run the sample starter code --I get an error: `Cannot find a class or type named "Set"` and this line comes back highlighted:

```
Set<String> tags = le.getCustomElements().getTags();
```

Am I missing something already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some default imports has gone in 2.0. Try
 `import java.util.*`
at the beginning of the code

Comment: The code already imports a bunch of components from `java.util` --  `import java.util.HashMap;` `import java.util.List;` `import java.util.Map;` -- do you know what I have to import to recognize `Set<String>`? * works, but I'd love to be more specific!

Comment: `import java.util.Set;`  But as far as i know set is an interface, so you will need to import the concrete Set you will use as well, like import `java.util.TreeSet;`